# Weblogic Stuck Thread on native method, RNI.initializeClass

Tags: java, multithreading, jsf, weblogic

We are using Weblogic 10.3.2 with jrockit 1.6 64 bit, our application is using jboss seam framework.. Number of stuck threads are increasing steadily. These stuck threads are just waiting , they are not spending any cpu cycle . All stuck thread's stack traces are same, their status are native_waiting.

Last java method call is   `com/sun/faces/application/ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:186)`.  And here is the source code of 186th line of ViewHandlerImpl class ;

```
  WriteBehindStateWriter stateWriter =
          new WriteBehindStateWriter(response.getWriter(),
                                     context,
                                     bufSize);
```

Full stack trace is attached to this email. Here is the  stack traces of some stuck threads ;

```
"[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '29' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" id=127 idx=0x230 tid=6974 prio=1 alive, native_waiting, daemon
    at pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2+185(:0)@0x3820a0aee9
    at eventTimedWaitNoTransitionImpl+71(event.c:90)@0x2b1ffc771ec8
    at syncWaitForSignalNoTransition+65(synchronization.c:28)@0x2b1ffc904312
    at innerNativeDoWait+1112(nativelock.c:614)@0x2b1ffc893f99
    at nativeWait+54(nativelock.c:721)@0x2b1ffc8942a7
    at clsEnsureInitialized+378(class.c:222)@0x2b1ffc72c61b
    at RJNI_jrockit_vm_RNI_initializeClass+19(trampoline.c:106)@0x2b1ffc90aba4
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.initializeClass(J)V(Native Method)
    at com/sun/faces/application/ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:186)
    at org/jboss/seam/jsf/SeamViewHandler.renderView(SeamViewHandler.java:87)
    at com/sun/facelets/FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:547)[optimized]
    at org/ajax4jsf/application/ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)[inlined]
    at org/ajax4jsf/application/AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)[optimized]
    at com/sun/faces/lifecycle/RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:109)[optimized]
    at com/sun/faces/lifecycle/Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)[optimized]



"[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '28' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" id=126 idx=0x22c tid=6973 prio=1 alive, native_waiting, daemon
    at pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2+185(:0)@0x3820a0aee9
    at eventTimedWaitNoTransitionImpl+71(event.c:90)@0x2b1ffc771ec8
    at syncWaitForSignalNoTransition+65(synchronization.c:28)@0x2b1ffc904312
    at innerNativeDoWait+1112(nativelock.c:614)@0x2b1ffc893f99
    at nativeWait+54(nativelock.c:721)@0x2b1ffc8942a7
    at clsEnsureInitialized+378(class.c:222)@0x2b1ffc72c61b
    at RJNI_jrockit_vm_RNI_initializeClass+19(trampoline.c:106)@0x2b1ffc90aba4
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.initializeClass(J)V(Native Method)
    at com/sun/faces/application/ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:186)
    at org/jboss/seam/jsf/SeamViewHandler.renderView(SeamViewHandler.java:87)
    at com/sun/facelets/FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:547)[optimized]
    at org/ajax4jsf/application/ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)[inlined]
    at org/ajax4jsf/application/AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)[optimized]
    at com/sun/faces/lifecycle/RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:109)[optimized]
    at com/sun/faces/lifecycle/Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)[optimized]
    at com/sun/faces/lifecycle/LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)[optimized]
    at javax/faces/webapp/FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)[optimized]
    at weblogic/servlet/internal/StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)[optimized]
    at weblogic/servlet/internal/StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)[inlined]
    at weblogic/servlet/internal/ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292)[optimized]
```

Do you have any idea why these threads are waiting?...

Comment: did you check if data is available to create stateWriter i.e, response.getWriter() and context